# Estimate for $\|a^2-b^2\|_{C^2(\Omega)}$ given that $\|a-b\|_{C^2(\Omega)} \leq c$

Tags: real-analysis

Given $$\|a-b\|_{C^2(\Omega)}\leq c$$ for some $a,b\in C^2(\Omega)$. Where $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is bounded and $c\in \mathbb{R}$. I need to show that

$$
\|a^2-b^2\|_{C^2(\Omega)}\leq \tilde{c}.$$

For some arbitrary $\tilde{c}$. Obviously this is trivial if we got $\|a+b\|_{C^2(\Omega)}\leq d$, with $d\in\mathbb{R}$ . But since I can not show that if the latter is true (or false) I wonder if we even need this. Is it possible to show the second estimate?

Comment: What is $\bar{c}$ in this context, exactly?

Comment: some arbitrary constant, it depends what we get for this estimate.

Comment: Th context is not clear. What are $a$ and $b$ and what is the  norm you are using?

Comment: thank you for the hint. I tried to add some context to make my question easier to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's fix $||a-b|| = c$, since if the difference is not the maximal allowed, we can trivially increase the difference of squares as well. Then $||(a+m) - (b+m)|| = c$.
$$||(a+m)^2-(b+m)^2|| = ||a^2 + 2am + m^2 - b^2 - 2bm - m^2|| = ||a^2 - b^2 + 2mc||$$

So by choosing $m$ we can get vectors $a+m$ and $b+m$ wit harbitrarily large difference of squares.